# Add coupon expiry date custom variable to the WooCommerce Follow-up Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, email-notifications

In my Woocommerce website I am using [Follow-up Emails plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/) for sending email to customer. On that Follow-up Emails I send coupon code to customer by using **`{coupon_code}`** email variables.

Now I would like to create a new custom variable for coupon expiry date.

Is there any way that we can hardcode in a coupon expiry date into the followup emails that customers receive?

Comment: I just don't use this plugin… sorry. As I can't test it, is not possible for me to get my code working … . But this is the good track: Follow-Up [Custom Variables](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automated-follow-up-emails-docs/custom-variables/)

Comment: When i using your code i got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function date() on null in

Comment: So you need to test first `$coupon_obj->get_date_expires()` to see if you get a WC_Date object.